# How to partition a table in scala with the proper name

Tags: scala, hive, partitioning

I have a large Dataframe in scala 2.4.0, that looks like this

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------+                                      
|              cookie|       updated_score|         probability|    date_last_score|partition_date|target|                 
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------+
|00000000000001074780|  0.1110987111481027| 0.27492987342938174|2019-03-29 16:00:00| 2019-04-07_10|     0|                
|00000000000001673799| 0.02621894072693878|  0.2029688362968775|2019-03-19 08:00:00| 2019-04-07_10|     0|                   
|00000000000002147908| 0.18922034021212567|  0.3520678649755828|2019-03-31 19:00:00| 2019-04-09_12|     1|            
|00000000000004028302| 0.06803669083452231| 0.23089047208736854|2019-03-25 17:00:00| 2019-04-07_10|     0|
```

and this schema:

```
root                                                               
 |-- cookie: string (nullable = true)                                       
 |-- updated_score: double (nullable = true)                                      
 |-- probability: double (nullable = true)                                      
 |-- date_last_score: string (nullable = true)                                         
 |-- partition_date: string (nullable = true)                                              
 |-- target: integer (nullable = false)
```

then I create a partition table and insert the data into database.table_name. But when I look up at hive database and type: show partitions database.table_name I only got partition_date=0 and partition_date=1, and 0 and 1 are not values from partition_date column.

I don't know if I wrote something wrong, there are some scala concepts that I don't understand or the dataframe is too large.

I've tried differents ways to do this looking up similar questions as:

```
result_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("table_name")
```

or

```
result_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("table_name")
```

In case it helps I provide some INFO message from scala:

Looking at this message, I think I got my result_df partitions properly.

```
19/07/31 07:53:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 11.0 in stage 2822.0 (TID 123456, ip-xx-xx-xx.aws.local.somewhere, executor 45, partition 11, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7767 bytes)
19/07/31 07:53:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 61.0 in stage 2815.0 (TID 123457, ip-xx-xx-xx-xyz.aws.local.somewhere, executor 33, partition 61, NODE_LOCAL, 8095 bytes)
```

Then, I am starting to saving the partitions as a Vector(0, 1, 2...), but I may only save 0 and 1? I don't really know.

```
19/07/31 07:56:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 35 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 2967 (MapPartitionsRDD[130590] at insertInto at evaluate_decay_factor.scala:165) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
19/07/31 07:56:02 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 2967.0 with 35 tasks
19/07/31 07:56:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ShuffleMapStage 2965 (MapPartitionsRDD[130578] at insertInto at evaluate_decay_factor.scala:165), which has no missing parents
```

My code looks like this:

```
val createTableSQL = s"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
                cookie              string,
                updated_score       float,  
                probability         float,
                date_last_score     string,
                target               int
            )
            PARTITIONED BY (partition_date string)
            STORED AS PARQUET
            TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESSION'='SNAPPY')
        """

spark.sql(createTableSQL)

result_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("table_name")
```

Given a dataframe like this:

```
val result = Seq(
         (8, "123", 1.2, 0.5, "bat", "2019-04-04_9"),
         (64, "451", 3.2, -0.5, "mouse", "2019-04-04_12"),
         (-27, "613", 8.2, 1.5, "horse", "2019-04-04_10"),
         (-37, "513", 4.33, 2.5, "horse", "2019-04-04_11"),
         (45, "516", -3.3, 3.4, "bat", "2019-04-04_10"),
         (12, "781", 1.2, 5.5, "horse", "2019-04-04_11")
```

I want to run: show partitions "table_name" on hive command line and get:

```
partition_date=2019-04-04_9                                         
partition_date=2019-04-04_10                                         
partition_date=2019-04-04_11                                      
partition_date=2019-04-04_12
```

Instead in my output is:

```
partition_date=0                                              
partition_date=1
```

In this simple example case it works perfectly, but with my large dataframe I get the previous output.

Comment: Try specifying the partitioning on the dataframe just before writing it, i.e.: `result_df.repartition("partition_date").write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("table_name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the number of partitions, use `repartition(numOfPartitions)`
To change the column you partition by when writing, use `partitionBy("col")`

example used together: `final_df.repartition(40).write.partitionBy("txnDate").mode("append").parquet(destination)`

Two helpful hints:

- Make your repartition size equal to the number of worker cores for quickest write / repartition. In this example, I have 10 executors, each with 4 cores (40 cores total). Thus, I set it to 40.
- When you are writing to a destination, don't specify anything more than the sub bucket -- let spark handle the indexing.

  - good destination: `"s3a://prod/subbucket/"`
  - bad destination: `s"s3a://prod/subbucket/txndate=$txndate"`

Comment: Using your answer, my dataframe is partitioned with the proper name, but it is saved in s3. In my case, I need all the partitions in hive. I tried: `result_df.repartition(40).write.partitionBy("partition_date").mode("append").parquet("database.table_name")` . I would really appreciate if you can tell me how to store this partitions in hive, so that my teammates can write queries.

Comment: Sure. Assuming this data is now in parquet, partitioned how you want it, and stored in s3, you can use the following syntax to create a hive table using your s3 data: CREATE TABLE `database`.`table` (`col1` STRING, `col2` STRING, `partionedcolumn1` DATE, `partionedcolumn2` INT)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  `inferSchema` 'true',
  `mergeSchema` 'true',
  path 's3a://path/to/data'
)
PARTITIONED BY (partionedcolumn1, partionedcolumn2)